# Reference for Book Design Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, combinatorial-designs

First, when i studied group action, i found out about design theory, then i got interested in it. But is there any good book to study design theory? especially for introduction and undergraduate student level. I knew about Design Theory book athor by Thomas Beth, D. Jungnickel, H. Lenz. But i find it too way long and i thought it is not introduction level. Pleas inform me if you know anything about it, thank You so Much!

Comment: Hughes and Piper, *Design Theory*, CUP, 1985.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Design Theory, by Hughes and Piper for a good introductory text.

Comment: Yes, I'm reading that book now, imo it is good enough for introductory text, so Thank you so much! And i have a plan, after finish it, i'll continue to read about design and structure in a more algebraic way (by reading 'Algebraic Design Theory' by Warwick de Launey & Dane Flannery, and 'Permutation groups and combinatorial structures' by Norman Biggs, do you think is it good plan or not? or i miss something in order (another book i should read to really understand about design theory and it's related algebraic))?

Answer (score 1):

There is book by Raghav Rao which i have spent about half an hour decades ago. But remember it being more algebraic:: Constructions and combinatorial problems in design of experiments" (corrected reprint of the 1971 Wiley ed.). New York

Comment: yeah, there is also 'Algebraic Design Theory' by Warwick de Launey & Dane Flannery, and 'Permutation groups and combinatorial structures' by Norman Biggs,and since im more in algebra, i will read those book after i finish reading design theory by hughes, anyway thank you for the references!